# Help calculating probability of dice rolls in a board game

Tags: probability, game-theory, dice

What is the probability of rolling a 6 symbol combination using 8 identical 6-sided dice (each dice having one duplicate symbol ie. d={A,A,B,C,D,E}), where the player is allowed discard one dice in order to reroll up to seven remaining?

Notes:
 - The game has eight identical six-sided dice. Each dice has five
   symbols, the sixth symbol is a duplicate ie. d={A,A,B,C,D,E}.
 - The player is allowed a one-time reroll up to seven of her dice (but it costs a one dice discard)
 - The goal is to match a *six-symbol combination* (I have linked an example below).

To be honest, I don't know where to begin. I have worked out that there are 210 possible combinations of 6-symbols.

I.e. n=5 symbols and r=6

$$\frac{(r+n-1)!}{r!(n-1)!} = \frac{10!}{6!4!} = 210$$

[Example of a symbol combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/748yI.jpg)

I really can't figure out how to calculate the probability though.

Comment: Thopson, Your question is unclear and difficult to understand.

Comment: I am struggling to be clearer, but I will have another go.

Comment: That certainly depends on the specific six-symbol combination and which symbol is the more frequent one.

Comment: When you say "the sixth symbol is a duplicate ie. d={A,A,B,C,D,E}", do you mean all the dice have the same duplicate symbol, or is there a die {A, B, B, C, D, E}?

Comment: The six dice are identical. All have the exact same symbol duplicated.

Comment: As mentioned above, the calculation is specific to a particular pattern. First, note that the joint distributions of $(A, B, C, D, E)$, the frequencies of each symbol among the initial roll of $n = 8$ dice follows $\text{Multinomial}(n; 1/3, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6, 1/6)$. Say your pattern to be match is $(a, b, c, d, e)$, which is the minimum frequencies needed of each symbol, and $a + b + c + d + e = 6$. The pattern is matched when $A \geq a, B \geq b, \ldots$. When there is no match in the initial roll, you reroll those in excess once again to see if there is a match.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you're after, you have a six-symbol "target" that you want to "cover" with the dice that you roll, and you're going to allow yourself two rounds to do so.  On the first round, you roll all eight dice, and you cover as many of the target symbols as you can with a matching die from that roll.  If you succeed in covering all six target symbols, you're done. Otherwise you take the remaining dice, set one of them aside, and roll the others, hoping that you can cover the remaining uncovered target symbols with the results of that second roll. Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is surely a closed-form solution as @BGM alluded to, you can also simulate the situation. Following is code to simulate a sampling distribution.

```
set.seed=126790
sims=100
probs=numeric(sims)
for(k in 1:sims)
{
  reps=1000
  rolls=matrix(NA,nrow=reps,ncol=8)
  for(i in 1:reps)
  {
    dice=c(NULL)
    for(j in 1:8)
    {
      dice=c(dice,sample(c('a','a','b','c','d','e'),1))
    }
    dice[sample(1:8,1)]=sample(c('a','a','b','c','d','e'),1)
    rolls[i,]=dice
  }
  rolls

  counter=0
  for(i in 1:reps)
  {
    if(length(grep('a',rolls[i,]))==6||
       length(grep('b',rolls[i,]))==6||
       length(grep('c',rolls[i,]))==6||
       length(grep('d',rolls[i,]))==6||
       length(grep('e',rolls[i,]))==6){
      counter=counter+1
    }
  }
  probs[k]=counter/reps
  cat(k,'\n')
}
probs
mean(probs)
sd(probs)
hist(probs)
```

In my run of the simulation, the mean probability of getting a 6 character match was $1.959$% with standard deviation $0.397$%. Because the standard error is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution, in 95% of repetitions of 100 sets of 8 rolls with one being replaced, between 1.18% and 2.74% will have a 6-character match. Of course this assumes a random replacement roll, but most people would try to behave strategically. However, I doubt it would change the results by very much. Additionally, this assumes the rolls are normally distributed. Visual analysis says the rolls are normally distributed.

[image]